# Newton Raphson Algorithm in R Programming

Tags: r

The text book exercise that I'm doing right now is implementing Newton-Raphson Algorithm in R Programming.

The code is:

```
#Inputs:
  s0 <- 2.36
  E <- 2.36 
  r <- 0.01 
  t <- 1 
  c <- 0.1875

#Initial value of volatility: 
  sigma <-0.10 
  sig <- rep(0,10)
  sig[1] <- sigma

#Newton-Raphson method:
for(i in 2:100){
  d1 <- (log(s0/E)+(r+sigma^2/2)*t)/(sigma*sqrt(t)) 
  d2 <- d1-sigma*sqrt(t) 
  f <- s0*pnorm(d1)-E*exp(r*t)*pnorm(d2)-c 

#Derivative of d1 w.r.t. sigma:
      d11 <- (sigma^2*t*sqrt(t)-(log(s0/E)+(r+sigma^2/2)*t)*sqrt(t))/(sigma^2*t) 

#Derivative of d2 w.r.t. sigma: 
      d22 <- d11-sqrt(t) 

#Derivative of f(sigma):
      f1 <- s0*dnorm(d1)*d11-E*exp(-r*t)*dnorm(d2)*d22 

#Update sigma: 
    sigma <- sigma - f/f1 
    sig[i] <- sigma
    if(abs(sig[i]-sig[i-1]) < 0.00000001){sig <- sig[1:i]; break}}sig
```

The result that I have when I type sig is 
[1] 0.1000000 0.2140636 0.2117527 0.2117864 0.2117859 0.2117859

The result should be based on the text book excercise:
[1] 0.1000000 0.1877024 0.1876218 0.1876218

What did I do wrong here? How come I have a different result?

Comment: Could you possible link to  text book exercise? I suspect a typo, either in the book or in your program.

Comment: No need for that. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions for `f` and `f1` don't match. The term `exp(r*t)` in the expression for `f` should read `exp(-r*t)` if the expression for `f1` is correct.
So `f` should be defined as

```
f <- s0*pnorm(d1)-E*exp(-r*t)*pnorm(d2)-c
```

Then the output will be

```
[1] 0.1000000 0.1877024 0.1876218 0.1876218
```

Finally do **not** use `c` as variable name; `c` is a builtin function.
Use something like `C` or even better `Cxx`.

Comment: Thank you, Bhas. That is really helpful.